# Java 8 List to Map with stream (avoid duplicates)

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, duplicates

I have two classes:

```
public class Adegae implements java.io.Serializable {
    private AdegaeId id;
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class AdegaeId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String gpi;
    private String mccode;
    private String aecode;
    ...
}
```

I also have a list that have elements with duplaicates of `aecode`:

```
List<Adegae> adegaes = ...
```

I'm building my map like so:

```
Map<String, Adegae> adegaeMap = adegaes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(adegae -> adegae.getId().getAecode().trim(), 
                    Function.identity()));
```

When I run my code I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key my.package.Adegae@678e3d87
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1245)
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
```

I wonder if there is a way to collect to a Map by dropping the duplicates at the same time.

Comment: Yes, you need to supply a mergeFunction as the 3rd parameter. See the linked question.

Comment: You would change adegaes from List to Set (Set avoid duplicates), can do something like : List<SomeObject> list = ...
Set<SomeObject> set = new HashSet<SomeObject>(list);

Comment: @DanielHernández Trickier since the duplicates aren't the object themselves but a property of the objects.

Comment: @Tunaki Thank you I upped your answer there - it helped

Comment: Does `Adegae` override the `equals()` method to use their `id` to test equality? If so, this is a slightly different question with a very different answer. Basing equality on the equivalence of ID is a common approach for persistent entities.

Comment: @erickson Why is it different? `equals` doesn't come into play here. The `mergeFunction` is used when elements are mapped to the same key, which in this case is the id. `equals` is unused. The linked question answers exactly that (`toMap` collector for both)

Comment: @Tunaki It's different because using `distinct()` , if applicable, expresses the intent more clearly and succinctly than a merge operator. Applicability depends on the notion of equality, so `equals()` does come in to play.

Comment: @erickson Indeed it does come into play for `distinct()` and you're right that it would make sense to have an `equals` comparing the id.

Comment: In the other question: while it's likely `Person` is an entity and *could* be tested by ID, it seems more about merging distinct entities by a business key, like `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Map<String, Adegae> adegaeMap = adegaes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(adegae -> adegae.getId().getAecode().trim(), 
                    Function.identity(), (e1, e2) -> e1));` may help in your case

Comment: That's exactly what Tunaki's answer is in the duplicate question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`distinct()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) method on `Stream` to eliminate the duplicates before further processing.

Comment: Trickier since the duplicates aren't the object themselves but a property of the objects.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the `equals()` method, but here, one would hope that objects with the same ID are equal.

Comment: This solution cant apply to my case since this is auto-generated class from Hibernate and I'm using only portion of the whole key.